# How to add activity when i long press my app?

Tags: java, android

I just want to add these widgets that leads to activity ( or whatever it is ) to my app. I can't find any similar questions in stackoverflow. I am using android studio with Java. [Here is an example for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4GFw.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts you can start with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are shortcuts here is the documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts